# ESS failed to run: ess-s-define-runners is void

Tags: init-file, ess, r

After upgrading packages in emacs, I have the following error message when trying to run R (M-x R): Symbol's function definition is void: ess-s-define-runners.
I can't find where the error is. Here's my ESS set-up in my init file, but I don't think it's coming from there:

```
(setq ess-eval-visibly-p nil)
(use-package polymode
:ensure f
:init (require 'poly-R)
      (require 'poly-markdown)
      (require 'poly-noweb)
:config
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md" . poly-markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Snw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rnw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd" . poly-markdown+r-mode)))
(add-hook 'ess-R-post-run-hook 'smartparens-mode)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-m") (lambda () (interactive) (insert " %>% ")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a known bug and updating to latest ESS version solves the problem. See https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/596.